# How can I implement an audit trail in a MS Access DB with composite PKs in juction tables?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to add an audit trail to a MS Access database that has several many-to-many relationships and a few subforms embedded into three principal subforms.

My DB is centered around one main table, from which there are several other tables linked, mainly in many-to-many relationships, so I'm using junction tables. Some of these junction tables have fields to record additional information, and, together with the FK fields they act as a composite PK. You can see it in more detail in the next picture (it's only part of it, but you can get the idea):

[DB schema cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNbIX.jpg)

Then, I have three main forms, each one with some subforms embedded. I want to be able to track every change, addition or deletion made through these forms and subforms, so I've tried using the method described in https://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut21.htm as a reference, but this only covers main forms. Another method, outlined in https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=284008 explains how to deal with subforms, but I'm stuck at the part where I have to add the code to call the audit trail from the subform (step 9), because it says "Replace "SubFormPrimaryKey" with the name of your SubForm's Primary Key in both lines of code", but, as I said lines above, my subforms are based in junction tables with composite PKs, so I don't know exactly what I need to put here:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If Me.NewRecord Then
    'Calls modAuditSub function to record new data to Audit Trail
    Call AuditChangesSub("SubformPrimaryKey", "NEW") 'original

Else
    'Calls modAuditSub function to record edits to Audit Trail
    Call AuditChangesSub("SubformPrimaryKey", "EDIT") 'original

End If
End Sub
```

So, my question is what can be the best way to solve this problem? I'm not too knowledgeable about VBA or programming in general, and because of that I'm having a hard time with this problem.

Comment: Add an autonumber field to junction tables and assign that as PK. The foreign key fields can be set as compound index without being defined as compound PK. Otherwise, modify code.

Comment: Try to add autonumber field, don't change indexes, refer to added field as PK in calls to audit function.

Comment: @June7 I see, I didn't considered that that was an option. I'll try and see if there's no problem. Thank you.

Comment: @4dmonster : Then, that means that I can use a single PK column in the audit function even if there's a composite PK in the table?

Comment: Either autonumber field OR compound fields can be defined as PK. You can save autonumber to audit table even if it is not defined as PK but since audit table is the only table saving junction table PK as FK, why not define autonumber as PK? This will make more sense if you need to join tables in query or set form/subform. The compound key is not used anywhere as FK. And if a junction table were to eventually have a dependent table, wouldn't you rather not have a compound FK? I would set autonumber as PK and then have compound index - just remove PK designation from compound index setup.